# How to use implement a text input form using JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to use JavaScript in an online examination assignment in HTML. As a requirement of the project, we have to use text input forms as well as radio buttons and the like. I have dealt with the part of radio buttons but for some reason my text input forms do not work. My problem will be clearly stated using this code snippet from the main project:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var test, name, matr, myname, count = 0;
    function form(){
        test = document.getElementById("test");

        test.innerHTML = "Count = "+count; 

        test.innerHTML += "<form> \
                            First name:<br> \
                        <input type='text' name='name'><br>\
                        <button onclick='check()'>Submit Answer</button>";
    }

    function check(){
        myname = document.getElementsByName("name");
        if (myname[1].value == "myname")
        {
            count++;
        }
        form();
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", form, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "test"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

What this code aims to do is that when the user inputs "myname" into the form called 'First name' and clicks 'Submit', the counter on the top should increment.

Can someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong and how it may be resolved.

Comment: To use strings on multiple lines, you need to end the current string and use the string concatenation operator `+` ([like this](http://pastebin.com/0kjrNzWK)). Also the index of an array starts at 0 in Javascript, so you'll want to use `myname[0]` (or potentially `myname[count]`.

Comment: @Pluto new lines can also be escaped as in OP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pluto mentioned, arrays in javascript start at 0. You can also look at tinkering with the form element. It is not closed nor is the type, get or post specified. I got it working in the example below by removing the form completely. This is because the button press was trying to submit the form and therefore load a new page.

https://jsfiddle.net/jpm68eub/

```
var test, name, matr, myname, count = 0;
function form() {
    test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.innerHTML = "Count = " + count;
    test.innerHTML += "</br> First name:<br> \
                    <input type='text' name='name'><br>\
                    <button onclick='check()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}

function check() {      
    myname = document.getElementsByName("name");
    if (myname[0].value == "myname") {
        count++;
    }
    form();
}
form();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent the default action of the onclick event. To do this, try something like this:

```
function check(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    myname = document.getElementsByName("name");
    if (myname[0].value == "myname")
    {
        count++;
    }
    form();
}
```

the above user was also correct about where javascript arrays start (they start at 0)